# Is the Lie derivative $L_{X}(\omega \wedge \mu)$ an exact form?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, lie-derivative

> Let $\omega$ be an $n$-form and $\mu$ be an $m$-form where both are acting on a manifold $M$. Is the Lie derivative $L_{X}(\omega \wedge \mu)$ where $X$ is a smooth vector field acting on $M$ an exact form?

I think it is but I've been unable to prove it, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No. Actually it commutes with $d$.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you know how to prove that it's integral over a smooth compact oriented manifold (of dimension $n+m$) without boundary is zero then? As I was trying to use Stoke's Theorem to do this.

Comment: I think this is not true in general. What's the integral that you're trying to compute?

Comment: $\int_M L_{X}(\omega \wedge \mu) =0$

Comment: Well in fact, $\int_M L_{X}(\omega) \wedge \mu = -\int_M \omega \wedge L_{X}(\mu)$

Comment: Don't you have any other restrictions? I believe this is not true in general. Is this result stated precisely in this form in some reference or exercise?

Comment: The question says: Let $M$ be a smooth compact oriented manifold without boundary of dimension $(n+m)$. Let $\omega$ be a smooth $n$ form on $M$ and $\mu$ be a smooth $m$ form on $M$. Prove the integral above.

Comment: I don't know how to prove it. If I have any idea, I will let you know immediately.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Use [Cartan's Magic Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_derivative#The_Lie_derivative_of_differential_forms), which says that the Lie derivative $\mathcal L_X$ of a differential form $\alpha$ satisfies
$$\mathcal L_X \alpha = \iota_X d \alpha + d (\iota_X \alpha) .$$
From the statement of the original problem in the comments, $L_X(\omega \wedge \mu)$ can be integrated, so $L_X(\omega \wedge \mu)$, and hence $\alpha := \omega \wedge \mu$, is a top form. In particular, $d \alpha = 0$; so, $\mathcal L_X \alpha$ is exact (and we can finish proving the claim in the comments with Stokes' Theorem).

NB that since we used the fact that $\omega \wedge \mu$ is a top form, this argument doesn't apply to the question in the full stated generality (i.e., to forms of general degree), and indeed, one can readily construct a counterexample using the above identity as a guide.

Comment: Why is $d\alpha =0$ ?

Comment: If $\alpha$ is an $N$-form, where $N$ is the dimension of the manifold, then $d\alpha$ is an $(N + 1)$-form on an $N$-manifold.

Comment: Of course! Thanks

Comment: You're welcome, I hope it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

In general this is not true. Recall that
$$
 L_X(\omega)  = i_x d\omega + d i_x\omega
$$
where you see that the right part is exact and the left part mustn't be. As an example for your case take $N$ a manifold with a non exact form $\mu$
and let $\omega$ be a 0-form (function) on $\mathbb{R}$ and define $M=N\times\mathbb{R}$ and note that the extension of $\mu$ is still not exact. Taking $\omega=x$ and $X=\partial_x$ where $x$ is the variable in $\mathbb{R}$ one sees
$$
 L_X(\omega\wedge \mu) = L_X(\omega)\wedge\mu +(-1)^0\omega\wedge L_X(\mu)=\mu
$$
since the projection of $X$ on $T_N$ vanishes.